# How to maximize SQL retrieval of binary images

Tags: c#, sql, swift, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am creating a Zillow-like IOS app. I am using Azure SQL (S-0 version) and C# for my backend. I store users data including the avatar of each user and the trips the person has been to (another table), where each user can have multiple trip pictures. I am using varbinary(max) to store those image types. So each user entity would have an average of 3 pictures.

my C# app retrieves all users with all their images and trip info and images using lazy loading in my linq-to-sql query.

The issue is naturally the time it takes to load all those date before user becomes able to consume it in the iphone clients (written in Swift). The end user will need all data to scroll through all those images. He at first load users, to see his images and read about him, and then scrolls up and would see  trips the other user has gone to. It won't make sense for the user to see only avatars and then wait for all trips for example, every time he calls.

What strategy should I do to minimize the load time!?

The thoughts I have had so far:

1. Use Azure Blobs to store images and consume that right from my swift clients to see if it will be any faster. I ditched that option because the extra slow retrieval of files because I have to first access the image file from my C# code, and make binary out of it so I can transmit it to my iphone client app.
2. Instead of using linq-to-sql, use the good ole ADO.NET to minimize the extra layer linq-to-sql. I didn't see much difference not even a second extra.
3. optimize my linq query by adding as much as possible in the where clause and avoid using loops. Make them all one select statement. The query spat by the linq-to-sql seems right. It didn't change much because the issue is the extra huge binary write ups being retrieved.
4. I mentioned it already above, using silent calls where I load only the user-related image and then when user sees summary, behind the scene I start loading all those trips, but the user will quickly need to check the trips. He will be confronted of having to wait again to see those trips. And I would have to initiate new calls to DB, which is expensive. Very undesirable!

What other suggestions should I try?

Comment: please help me out and remove the on hold.

Comment: The solution is not as broad as the admins may've thought. It is to check the size of the images. Anything above a 1 mg is too big of picture to resend across the wire especially if there many of them. I reset my images to 300x300 and noticed huge difference.

Comment: One other note to improve the speed is to move your DB from S0 to S2. You can figure out this hint when you start a new DB in Azure, it defaults to S2. There is some more care given to starting point of S2 and on. Also not too broad answer!